# neo4j ServiceUnavailableException when initialising the driver in android application

Tags: android, neo4j, android-emulator

I am trying to connect my local neo4j server database with the android application running in the android emulator. This is my test code

```
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.*;

public class Database {

private  Driver driver;

private static final String TAG = "Database";
public Database(){
        driver = GraphDatabase.driver( "bolt://10.0.2.2:7687", AuthTokens.basic( "neo4j", "neo4j" ) );

}


public void printStations()
{
    Session session = driver.session();

    // Auto-commit transactions are a quick and easy way to wrap a read.
    StatementResult result = session.run(
            "match(s:Station) return s.name as name");
    // Each Cypher execution returns a stream of records.
    while (result.hasNext())
    {
        Record record = result.next();
        // Values can be extracted from a record by index or name.
        Log.i(TAG, record.get("name").asString());
    }
}


public void close() {
    driver.close();
}
```

but GraphDatabase.driver is throwing an exception when initialising the driver. 
    org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to process request: java.io.EOFException: Read error

I am using neo4j java driver 1.4.6 over the neo4j 3.3.1. Can someone help me to find out a solution please?

Comment: I would recommend using the Rest API to connect and communicate with neo4j server

Comment: Thanks @VivekKumar, I didn't test it yet. I think that will work because I can access neo4j server from the emulator using both http and https protocol. But I think there is a problem when using bolt port. Is there a way to test the bolt port from the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

you should use from compatible version of driver .I used from  below versions
org.neo4j 3.5.12
org.neo4j.driver 4.0.0